# Calculating DRBD Meta Size

Tags: drbd

I've read through the documentation provided at http://www.drbd.org/users-guide/ch-internals.html#s-meta-data-size to establish the DRBD meta size, but I'm struggling to correlate that to actual disk sizes and file system sizes.

Is there a way that I can retrieve the file system size in sectors (along with the block device), to get the right value for the meta data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We use a script in-house for calculating `DRBD` meta sizes for LVM partitions.

This is a script that just takes the block device as an argument.

Eg. `metacalc.sh /dev/vg1/root`

This is the contents of the script ... (it also happens to give the command to resize the file system on the `DRBD` disk too).

### metacalc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

which bc >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: bc is not installed"
    exit 1
fi

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Error: Please supply block device path"
    echo "Eg. /dev/vg1/backups"
    exit 1
fi

DEVICE=$1

SECTOR_SIZE=$( blockdev --getss $DEVICE )
SECTORS=$( blockdev --getsz $DEVICE )
MD_SIZE=$( echo "((($SECTORS + (2^18)-1) / 262144 * 8) + 72)" | bc )
FS_SIZE=$( echo "$SECTORS - $MD_SIZE" | bc )

MD_SIZE_MB=$( echo "($MD_SIZE / 4 / $SECTOR_SIZE) + 1" | bc )
FS_SIZE_MB=$( echo "($FS_SIZE / 4 / $SECTOR_SIZE)" | bc )

echo "Filesystem: $FS_SIZE_MB MiB"
echo "Filesystem: $FS_SIZE Sectors"
echo "Meta Data:  $MD_SIZE_MB MiB"
echo "Meta Data:  $MD_SIZE Sectors"
echo "--"
echo "Resize commands: resize2fs -p "$DEVICE $FS_SIZE_MB"M; drbdadm create-md res"
```

**The only prerequisite** is that `bc` is installed

1. Centos - `yum install bc`
2. Debian/Ubuntu - `apt-get install bc`